# How to reverse the output of crc.crc16ccitt to the original input?

Tags: javascript, decode, crc, crc16

How to reverse the output of crc.crc16ccitt to the original input. Used npm module named crc.

**Package used:** https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/crc

**Method used:** crc.crc16ccitt(inputString)

Comment: If the CRC algorithm has been properly implemented, then you will not be able to reverse it to get the original input.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have just used the npm module. Looks like this npm is little popular, hope its properly implemented. Why its not reversible?

Comment: Because a CRC is a hash of the input. A hashed value should not, by definition, be reversible

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I read CRC is not actually a hashing? In that case, it should be reversible right? Honestly tried many ways to reverse this, but nothing worked for me so far..

Comment: A correctly implemented CRC is absolutely a hash function, and is not reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the input is two bytes or less, you cannot reconstruct it from a two-byte CRC.

Comment: Any sample with generation of a hash and reversing it back to the original string would be of more helpful..

Comment: You actually have a two-byte CRC of a two-byte message, and you want to know what the message is?